# combine two select statement in two column?

Tags: mysql

i Have two select statement

1

```
select Start_Date
    from table1  where Start_Date not in (
    select End_Date
    from table1)
```

2

```
 select End_Date from table1
    where End_Date not in (
        select Start_Date
            from table1
        )
```

i want to combine two select statement in different column when i use union all it give me one column with the result of two queries i want each query result in different column but when i use inner join like that

```
select a.End_Date , b.Start_Date from
( select End_Date from table1
where End_Date not in (
select Start_Date
from table1
) ) a

join

(select Start_Date
from table1 where Start_Date not in (
select End_Date
from table1)
) b
on 1=1
```

it giving me result every record is repeating four times help me what i do next ??

Comment: How should the two dates be paired up on each row of the results?

Comment: Could you show some sample input and the desired result?

Answer (score 10):

If each of your queries returns only 1 row you can use:

```
SELECT 
(select Start_Date
    from table1  where Start_Date not in (
        select End_Date
        from table1)
) AS StartDate,
 (select End_Date from table1
    where End_Date not in (
        select Start_Date
        from table1)
 ) AS EndDate
```

If your queries return more than 1 row you have to choose a different solution:

You can use `UNION`:
(You'll have the two queries misaligned with "NULL" in the other column)

```
(select Start_Date, Null AS EndDate
    from table1  where Start_Date not in (
         select End_Date
         from table1)
) 
UNION
(select  Null As StartDate, End_Date 
    from table1
    where End_Date not in (
        select Start_Date
        from table1)
 )
```

You can use `JOIN`
If you have a field to use as "Join On" you can use this field, if not you can add a field to join (but you need to check data returned to avoid errors)
Also you have to check what kind of join may be good for you (Inner - Left - rigth)
In the example I add a field to join and use an Inner Join:

```
SELECT Start_Date, End_Date
FROM
(select 1 as InnerId, Start_Date
    from table1  where Start_Date not in (
        select End_Date
        from table1)
) As Tab1
 INNER JOIN
 (select  1 as InnerId, End_Date from table1
    where End_Date not in (
        select Start_Date
        from table1)
 ) AS Tab2
USING(InnerId)
```

Comment: Isn't this the same as the other two answers, just less detailed?

Comment: @Barmar This isn't a join. Simply gives a column for each Select. You can give a name to columns using "as columnName" after ")" of each select

Comment: You can't put a `(select)` subquery into the `SELECT` clause if it returns more than 1 row.

Comment: I don't understand your comment. The other answers didn't have joins. They've since been deleted because they didn't work.

Comment: @Barmar I'm writing from phone and can't copy/paste. I'll try to edit my answer to be more clear

Comment: I don't know how easy it is to do from your phone, but try confirming that it actually works first.

Comment: @Barmar Sorry but phone won't Select text. I'll be on a pc in 10 hours. It is the same of next answer without "* from"

Comment: @Barmar I edited my answer and add some alternatives

Comment: What's the purpose of `InnerId` if it's always the same? If you don't have a column to join on, use `CROSS JOIN`, which produces a full cross-product between the two tables. MySQL also allows you to leave out the `ON` clause of `INNER JOIN`, and it does a cross join.