# SQL query help using two WHERE clauses

Tags: sql

I have a table with data spanning about two weeks.  I want to see the average for the first 7 days and then the next 8.

I have tried various JOINS with no luck.  I am new to SQL so I am probably missing something simple.

Basically these queries work.  How do I combine them?

```
select count(Field)/8 
from TABLE 
WHERE Publish_date >= '04/05/19'

select count(Field)/7 
from TABLE 
WHERE Publish_date < '04/05/19'
```

Comment: (1) Tag with the database you are using.  (2) Sample data and desired results would help.  (3) What does `COUNT()` have to do with "average"?

Comment: Could you share some sample data and expected resutls?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [combine two select statement in two column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33790771/combine-two-select-statement-in-two-column)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really need to combine them, then you can do sub-queries:

```
SELECT
    (
        SELECT SUM(Field)/8 
        FROM TABLE 
        WHERE Publish_date >= '04/05/19'
    ) as date1,
    (
        SELECT SUM(Field)/7 
        FROM TABLE 
        WHERE Publish_date < '04/05/19'
    ) as date2
```

---

Please note that you wish to use `SUM` instead of `COUNT`, because `COUNT` just get rows count, not it's values summed up.

Comment: Thanks Justinas!  This worked!  I know SUM vs COUNT, in this case Count works.

Answer (score 0):

Just use UNION ALL between them like this:

```
select count(Field)/8 from TABLE WHERE Publish_date >= '04/05/19'
    UNION ALL
    select count(Field)/7 from TABLE WHERE Publish_date < '04/05/19'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try the `AVG()` function. If your dates are proper, count of  days will be taken care automatically.

2 weeks => 14 days. How did you get 7+8 = 15 days ?

If you need two different rows -

```
;with t (val, dt) as (
    select 183, getdate()-6 union all
    select 183, getdate()-5 union all
    select 183, getdate()-4 union all
    select 183, getdate()-3 union all
    select 183, getdate()-2 union all
    select 183, getdate()-1 union all
    select 183, getdate() union all --< cutoff date
    select 183, getdate()+1 union all
    select 183, getdate()+2 union all
    select 183, getdate()+3 union all
    select 183, getdate()+4 union all
    select 183, getdate()+5 union all
    select 183, getdate()+6 union all
    select 20, getdate()+7 
)
select 'first-half' , AVG(val) averg from t where dt < getdate()
union all
select 'second-half' , AVG(val) averg from t where dt >= getdate()
```

Comment: ranit.b - I'll have to try the Union function later. Thanks!  The actual range is the 29th-12th, so about 2 weeks, but 15 days.

Comment: `UNION` is not a function but an _operator_. `AVG` is a _function_. Always post your questions along some sample input data and expected output. This really helps for suggesting clearer answers. Enjoy!

Comment: Thanks for the clarification ranit.b!